# Round the decimal Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I have a column that has Numerical data(float) and need to round up the only the decimal values.

```
    Actual Value  Rounded Value
    2370.09 -->   2370.10
    2370.07 -->   2370.08
    2370.05 -->   2370.06
    2370.01 -->   2370.02
    2370.02 -->   2370.02
    2370.04 -->   2370.04
    2370.06 -->   2370.06
    2370.08 -->   2370.08
```

If the decimal value(after period) is odd then it should be increased by 0.01 and if its even then there is no change in the value.

I've tried `SELECT ROUND(Actual Value, 1)`

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the modulus example in the other answer provided by @scsimon, you could do this without a case statement like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    n numeric(10,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @t (n)
VALUES (2370.09)
    , (2370.07)
    , (2370.06)
    , (0)
    , (1.01)
    , (1.09)
    , (1.9)
    , (9999.99);

SELECT (t.n + (t.n % 0.02))
FROM @t t;
```

```
╔══════════════════╗
║ (No column name) ║
╠══════════════════╣
║          2370.10 ║
║          2370.08 ║
║          2370.06 ║
║             0.00 ║
║             1.02 ║
║             1.10 ║
║             1.90 ║
║         10000.00 ║
╚══════════════════╝
```

Comment: it won't make much difference for a small dataset, but with a large number of rows, not doing the `CASE` might make quite a bit of difference.

Comment: Won't hurt to make it into a function either if used often.

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRoundOddDecimal (@t decimal(9,2))
RETURNS decimal(9,2)
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN (@t + @t%0.02)
END

Comment: @Bistabil - you may want to be careful using a function in SQL Server like that.  It will drastically slow down large queries.

Comment: @MaxVernon I am careful, scalar function behaves the same as your solution. Costs are the same, it just provides re-usability and more predictable scale and precision.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a case statement with modulus. This is an easy method to check the last digit and see if it's even or odd, and then handle the simple addition.

```
declare @var decimal(6,2) = 2370.07
select
    case 
        when right(@var,1) % 2 != 0 
        then @var + 0.01 
        else @var 
    end
```

Or, using your schema

```
select
    [Actual Value]
    ,[RoundedValue] = 
                      case 
                           when right([Actual Value],1) % 2 != 0 
                           then [Actual Value]+ 0.01 
                           else [Actual Value]
                      end
From Your Table
```

Comment: Note that as of SQL Server 2012, this can be done with `IIF` instead - `SELECT [Actual Value], IIF(right([Actual Value],1) % 2 != 0, [Actual Value]+ 0.01 , [Actual Value]) as [Rounded Value]`

Comment: FYI, `IIF` performance on SQL Server is much worse than a simple `CASE WHEN` statement.

Comment: @MaxVernon this I did not know! I would t have expected it to be though. Does it have to do with short circuiting?

Comment: I think `IIF` is implemented as a black-box, similarly to `FORMAT`, which performs terribly too.  I'm not certain as to the details why.  Might make an interesting question on [dba.se]

Comment: After some testing I plan to tomorrow. Thanks as always @MaxVernon

Comment: and, of course, it only ever shows up on queries with a huge number of rows